# can vs can't distinction, and can't followed by a vowel sound

Tags: american-english, pronunciation, phonetics, ipa

Edit: I am talking about American English, particularly the one spoken in the Western United States

I understood from [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/40332/can-and-cant-how-and-why?rq=1&newreg=9abb5ff51fa14933870eaf1ff4ccb07d) post that there are mainly these ways to distinguish between the two:

1. the -nt in *can't* triggers pre-fortis clipping so the preceding vowel is much shorter compared to that in *can*.
2. the *n* and *t* in *can't* have the same articulatory position and the *t* sound is usually just glottalized
3. *can* is usually unstressed with the <s>bed vowel</s> schwa or the BIT (/ɪ/) vowel but *can't* is always stressed.

Now I have two questions here:

1. How would you accurately transcribe *can't* using the ipa? maybe **[kæ̃ʔ]** or **[kæ̃nʔ]**?
2. The top comment in the post linked above also mentions that if "can't" is followed by a word beginning with a vowel, then the 't' reemerges and gets combined with the next word from syllabification. But when I listened to some samples for the word "can't ask" in youglish, I couldn't hear that supposedly reemerging sound 't' at all. It should have sounded like 'can task' if that t were to reemerge but it just sounded like 'cannask' to me. [Here's](https://youglish.com/pronounce/can%27t%20ask/english/us?) the link. How would you transcribe "can't ask" based on some of the audios from above?

Comment: For this British English speaker, points 1 and 3 are false. The vowel in _can_ is, for me, schwa when unstressed, or if stressed, the one in _bad_, never _bit_ (which sounds like a parody of US English) or _bed_ (which just sounds bizarre). _can't_, whether stressed or unstressed, always has a longer vowel than _can_. Point 2 is however true for me.

Comment: @tea-and-cake I have fixed the question

Comment: Ah!  Just as I posted an answer specifically about British English!  I'm not qualified to answer for American dialects but I think the answer will be similar to mine.  In some dialects the difference may be hard to perceive, and in that case speakers will deliberately emphasise _can't_ somehow (by for instance aspiration, double-pronouncing the /t/ or whatever).

Answer (score 1):

In your link I hear something like ['kʰæənd æəsk].  But for this British English speaker, points 1 and 3 are false. The vowel in *can* is, for me, something like schwa when unstressed, or if stressed, the one in *bad*, never *bit* (which sounds like a parody of US English) or *bed* (which just sounds bizarre). *can't*, whether stressed or unstressed, always has a longer vowel than *can*. Point 2 is however true for me.

I don't think you'll find a single simple answer.  There is always a difference but it depends on accent and context.

Let's take the phrase *I (1) can't ask you to do that, but I (2) *can* task you to do it. But she (3) can ask you, and he (3) can't task you*.

Here, both *can* and *can't* are stressed so the vowels aren't reduced.

In a Northern English accent where *can't* has the same vowel as *can*, the relevant phrases are pronounced something like 1 ['kʰænt ʔæsk], 2 ['kʰæ:n tʰæsk], 3 ['kʰæ:n æsk], 4 ['kʰæ:nt.tʰæsk].

In other British dialects where the vowels differ, *can* would be realised as [kʰæn] or [kʰən], *can't* as [kʰɑːnt] or [kʰɑːnʔ].

Answer (score 1):

Your point number 1 and 3 aren't true for most people. *-nt* doesn't trigger pre-fortis clipping, in fact, the opposite happens in some varieties of English (i.e. the preceding vowel lengthens). *Can* is usually unstressed and is pronounced with a schwa as you say, but when it's stressed, it has /æ/ in AmE. I've never heard it with the BIT vowel (/ɪ/ -- usually referred to as KIT). Also, we can't say that *can't* is always stressed, because it's definitely unstressed in some contexts.

**Transcriptions of *can't*:** Even the pronunciation of a single word varies from person to person, so I can't represent the pronunciation of every speaker of American English, but here's my best shot:

- [kʰæ̃nʔ]<sup>1</sup>
- [kʰæ̃ʔ]
- [kʰæ̃nt]
- [kʰæ̃t]
- [kʰæ̃ːʔt]
- [kʰæ̃ːʔ]
- [kʰæ̃ːʔt̚]<sup>2</sup>
- it's also possible though that the [k] might become a bit fronted<sup>3</sup> in anticipation of the following front vowel, in which case [k̟ʰ-]

it can be one of the above in AmE

For *can't ask*, I heard something along the lines of [ˈkʰæ̃ɾ̃æsk] (or perhaps [ˈkʰæ̃ːɾ̃æsk]) from most speakers on Youglish.

[ɾ̃] is called a *nasalised flap*. [ɾ] is called a flap and appears in words like *be**tt**er, wa**t**er, bi**tt**er* (between a stressed and an unstressed vowel) in AmE. Nasalised flap, on the other hand, occurs in words such as *wi**n.t**er, cou**n.t**er, i**n.t**ernet*. When a stressed syllable ends in an *n* and another (unstressed) syllable starts with a *t*, the *-nt-* usually becomes [ɾ̃] in some (most?) American accents. You can listen to [ˈwɪntɚ ˈwɪnɚ ˈwɪɾ̃ɚ] [here at Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:En-us-winter-winner-flapped-unflapped.oga). The first one is *winter* with a [t], the second one is *winner* and the third one is *winter* with a nasalised flap.

Here's what *Trask's Historical Linguistics* says about the nasalisation of the vowel preceding a nasal:

> Many English-speakers, particularly in North America, have conspicuous nasalization of vowels before a nasal consonant, in words like *can’t, don’t* and *punt*, and it takes only a slight delay in making the alveolar closure for the [n] to disappear altogether. Hence many Americans pronounce these words as [kæ̃t], [dõũt] and [pʌ̃t] with the nasalization of the vowel solely responsible for distinguishing these words from *cat* [kæt], *dote* [dout] and *putt* [pʌt].

Also from [this answer on Linguistics SE](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/a/13184):

> When flapping applies to /t/ in "entertain", "ninety", /n/ actually deletes and the preceding vowel becomes nasalized, so you have [ɛ̃ɾ̃ɹ̩ˈtʰɛjn, ˈnãj̃ɾ̃ɪj]

So I would transcribe *can't ask* as **[ˈkʰæ̃ɾ̃æsk]**.

---

NOTES:

1. The superscript h [**ʰ**] represents [aspiration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspirated_consonant); the puff of air that accompanies some consonants such as *p, t, k* when they're at the start of a stressed syllable.
2. [t̚] is an unreleased 't', meaning there's [no audible release](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_audible_release).
3. ‘An advanced or fronted sound is one that is pronounced farther to the front of the vocal tract than some reference point’ ([Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_articulation))

Comment: See [this article](http://www.antimoon.com/how/flap-t.htm) for nasalised flap.